# Start bluetooth adapter without pop up

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

How can we start the bluetooth adapter in background without the validation popup ?

normal way :

```
Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
context.startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
context.sendBroadcast(enableBtIntent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to enable bluetooth without using an Intent, you can try this:

```
BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter.enable();
```

you also need to add the BLUETOOTH and BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permission to your manifest file.